# PHP Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto?

Tags: php

I'm using swiftMailer to send email using SMTP directly.

I get this strange error:

```
2011/09/23 17:59:01 [error] 489#0: *1032 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:func(119):reason(252) in /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 271
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 271
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://mail.xxxxx.net:587 (Unknown error) in /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 271
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host mail.xxxxxxxx.net [ #0]' in /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:273
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(66): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection()
#1 /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(116): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array)
#2 /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#3 /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/email.php(23): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/nginx/websites/example.com/www/inc/lib/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 273" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /email.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com"
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Does your mail server accept port 587 connections?

Comment: sure, I'm using 587 with my Thunderbird

Comment: is it a PHP bug? I'm using: PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:00:17)

Comment: try running the script from the command line, which'd bypass any lockdowns suhosin's done.

Comment: Yes I tried with command line, I get the same error.

Comment: Allright, then probably something's munged with PHP's ssl support.

Comment: Verify that openssl is loaded and configured correctly on your server.

Comment: Yes it is loaded correctly.... The MTA is on the same server...openssl works perfectly with it

Comment: Yes it is loaded correctly.... The MTA is on the same server...openssl works perfectly with it

Answer (score 2):

The "failure to enable crypto" means that it was unable to secure the connection - check to be sure that you are successfully passing a certificate, and that your passphrase is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with my mac (OSX Sierra). I uploaded php and cert to my server, ran it, and the notification was delivered.

Duplicate: [APNS + PHP "stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995197/apns-php-stream-socket-client-failed-to-enable-crypto/41201588#41201588)

Answer (score 0):

This error is quite typically that you have tried to contact an invalid port in my experience.

Try `telnet mail.xxxxx.net 587`, and if you do not get anything about an escape character then it is not the right port.

If you have access, examine the server config to see if you are trying to access a port which is not exposed for ssl streams. Try the `telnet` command again to probe other possible candidate ports