# APNS + PHP "stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto"

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, push, apns-php

I'm having trouble with using APNS with PHP and getting the following message:

```
stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
```

The problem only happens sometimes, and other times it would actually send the push.

Since I have the test script on a loop of 10 iterations, I would sometimes get this:

```
stream_socket_client(): SSL: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm testing using the sandbox server `tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

Here is what I tried:

- I tried to reissue the PEM and all certificates with it.
- I played around with the request protocol `sslv3://` and `tls://`.
- I played around with the passphrase (push worked without the passphrase btw)
- I tried searching stackoverflow for a solution and nothing worked.
- Checked pem file permissions `644`
- Checked pem parent directories permissions `755`

It seems that all the solutions I found on Google and SO are people having problem pushing altogether.

I feel like the service is rate limited maybe? Because we waited a while (around 15 minutes) and then tried it again, and was able to successfully push around 100 messages until I started getting that message again.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this, Samer? My situation looks so much like yours! Well in fact I was able to send apns sometimes, but lately I realized my script spent months trying to send apns one at a time even after my certificate has expired...I'm asking myself if Apple just blocked my IP and maybe now I stopped trying to connect they will unblock my IP after a certain amount of time...

Comment: Nevermind, check my answer about changing Apple's servers!! Now I use ssl://api.push.apple.com:443 instead of ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sandbox push service is rate limited.  I have experienced this myself when testing but have never encountered any such limit using the production API.

You might also be hitting their other protections.

Are you opening a connection, sending a message, closing connection and then looping and doing it all over again?

That will get your notifications dropped.  Apple wants you to send several push notifications using the same connection, not a new one each time.

> **Best Practices for Managing Connections**
>
> You may establish multiple connections to the same gateway or to
>   multiple gateway instances. If you need to send a large number of
>   remote notifications, spread them out over connections to several
>   different gateways. This improves performance compared to using a
>   single connection: it lets you send the remote notifications faster,
>   and it lets APNs deliver them faster.
>
> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications;
>   **don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack.** You should
>   leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to
>   your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

From Apple Docs @  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

Comment: That makes sense, I usually keep the connection open until sent to all devices so should be good on that part. Let's hope production is good. Thanks!

Comment: lol sorry didn't know i had to press the bounty button to award it. I thought it was automatic.

Comment: As said in @greg_diesel answer, "Apple wants you to send several push notifications using the same connection, not a new one each time".
Many libraries use stream_socket_client to send messages with option STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT. Try to change it to STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT

Answer (score 5):

My PHP  code was generating following error:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /private/tmp/t.php on line 12
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /private/tmp/t.php on line 12
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /private/tmp/t.php on line 24
```

The problem was, the damn certificate, expired the day before yesterday! :-) Can you believe this?

So, I need to recreate my PEM file.

Comment: YEAH! I recreated my certificate and it worked. Thanks!
Just to remind how to generate the certificate:
      openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary recreate your pem file

that error happens when you use an incorrect PassPhrase

regards
Emiliano

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Disappeared after giving write permission for 'everyone' for the .pem file.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem because I foolishly forgot to include the file extension (.pem) when supplying the file path for local_cert.

Answer (score 0):

**few checks** :

1. device token should be - with out `spaces` and with out `<` or `>`
2. make sure the path of certificate is correct and  expired date of it.
3. make sure the passphrase you are using is the one u used to make certificate

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with my mac (OSX Sierra). I uploaded php and cert to my server, ran it, and the notification was delivered.

Answer (score 0):

I tried examples from book of Marin Todorov iOs 6 by Tutorials.
And before I could send push notifications for automatical update I had a lot of headache cause of handshake error - *`stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto`*.

I did all of what I found in Stackoverflow - changed permissions on certificate and others.

What I did eventually?

I created selfsigned SSL certificate and setup Apache for serving SSL.
Also I changed SSL protocol from ssl to tls in hostname:

```
tls://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

After that service works.